# How to set default value about RxJS in Angular form

Tags: angular, rxjs

Here's [example link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-rxjs)
there are two inputs element, Only when both inputs are in touch will  output the values in console.
how to do change one input value will trigger output?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use a `startWith` pipe :

```js
const username$ = this.form.get('username')
  .valueChanges
  .pipe(startWith(this.form.get('username').value))

const password$ = this.form.get('password')
  .valueChanges
  .pipe(startWith(this.form.get('password').value))

combineLatest(username$, password$)
.pipe(
  map(([username, password]) => ({username, password}))
)
.subscribe(res => console.log(res))
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-rxjs-xrklk2?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: thanks, it works, I just found we can also use `this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(res => console.log(res));` thanks again.